# Match lines from a text file (image listing) in SPECIFIED order using batch, JScript (JREPL ?) or VBScript?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

The environment is WindowsXP (possibly upgrading to Windows7 soon).
I am allowed to run scripts but NOT allowed to install tools.

**TASK:**

Output matched lines from a Log.txt file in **same order** as list of search terms (Tokens.txt, one token per line), which have been extracted from StartingList.txt (a text listing of filepaths, available as %1 to a batch file).

**PROBLEMS:** (and work-arounds)

**Method1 below:** Command line FindStr **changes** the order (vs order of the listed search terms).  A work-around is to use a FOR loop:

**Method2 below:** Batch FOR loop with FindStr is **very slow** and **changes** some characters (outside the range of 32 to 126, command line fonts and character sets may not agree with the underlying Windows Unicode support - see question 157225 for more info on char aspects). A **workaround** is to ban use of characters outside the 'safe' range of 32 thru 126, **or** run a tail-end 'find and replace' on any changed characters.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS: (This is where I need help please ...)**

An equivalent unicode-aware VBScript or JScript (possibly using JREPL too) would solve the slow speed and support all Unicode characters.

An example of a functionally equivalent FOR loop in these scripting languages would help, please.

The closest JREPL methods are by dbenham at question 1052645 and at:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=39534#p39534

Example StartingList.txt:

```
D:\Pics\2005-03-27 Bristol\2005-03-27 DSC_0016#.JPG  
D:\Pics\2005-03-26 Brighton\2005-03-26 DSC_0014#^{!k¿m.JPG  
D:\Pics\2005-03-26 London\2005-03-26 DSCN0015#.JPG  
D:\Pics\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-30 _DSC0019#.JPG  
D:\Pics\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-29 P01_0018#.JPG
```

Example Tokens.txt:

```
DSC_0016#  
DSC_0014#  
DSCN0015#  
_DSC0019#  
P01_0018#
```

Example Log.txt:

```
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-30 _DSC0019#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-29 P01_0018#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-28 DSC_0017#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-27 Bristol\2005-03-27 DSC_0016#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-26 London\2005-03-26 DSCN0015#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-26 Brighton\2005-03-26 DSC_0014#^{!k¿m.JPG
```

Example StartingList(updated).txt:

```
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-27 Bristol\2005-03-27 DSC_0016#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-26 Brighton\2005-03-26 DSC_0014#^{!k¿m.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-26 London\2005-03-26 DSCN0015#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-30 _DSC0019#.JPG  
F:\Pics\Edited\2005-03-28 Bath\2005-03-29 P01_0018#.JPG
```

Method 1:

```
::method1
type nul >%1
findstr /G:Tokens.txt Log.txt >%1(updated).txt
```

Method 2:

```
::method2
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
type nul >%1
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Tokens.txt) do (
    findstr /C:"%%i" Log.txt >>%1(updated).txt
    )
```

Method 3:

Ideally, a solution something like this, possibly using JREPL, passing in search parameters as a text list, perhaps using a pipe in or out, possibly to another JREPL?  The solutions to question 850183 seem close, but my pensioner-brain cannot bridge the gap - apologies for my poor attempt:

Otherwise a pure JScript or VBScript example would help, please.

```
::method3 [pseudo Jscript in square brackets is where I need help please]
type nul >%1
Call jrepl "[Read in Tokens.txt, match each token IN LISTED ORDER]" "[if (token==match, output matched line)]" /jmatch /jbeg "[cnt]" /f Log.txt /o >%1(updated).txt
```

Comment: What characters are changed when you use the `for` loop?

Comment: Method 2 works for me, using your example log.txt and tokens.txt.

Comment: The inverted question mark is a good one to look at (Alt+168). It changes to the umlaut (superscript double dots) on my WinXP.  Also, Method2 takes a good hour or so to run through a typical log file of image filepaths. Yikes!

Comment: On the other hand, Method1 is done in the blink of an eye, but outputs in the default order of the FindStr function.

Comment: Alt+168 is preserved here (Windows 7). I can't think of an obvious way to fix method 1 or method 2 speed. I suspect dbenham is required to answer method 3 if he wanders past and sees the question.